# Microsoft Graph Issue with Authorisation Code

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to allow access to Microsoft accounts using the instructions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user.

I have the first two steps working, the issue is occurring when I try to use the Authorisation Code that is returned after the user has granted permission to the application.

I am a bit confused because in the example above the Authorization response has an Authorization Code that looks like a `GUID` with an extra character at the start. From the example: `M0ab92efe-b6fd-df08-87dc-2c6500a7f84d`. This looks like what I am getting.

However in step three, Getting a Token, the Authorization code now looks very different. Again from the example: `OAAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLWQJVzCTE9UkP3pSx1aXxUjq3n8b2JRLk4OxVXr...` I am guessing that this is a `Base64 string` of some sort but I tried simply encoding the `GUID` like code from the previous step but that hasn't worked.

Am I missing a step here that somehow turns the initial Authorization code into a new format?

If I use the Authorization code that I receive directly I get a 401 response when trying to get an Access Token.

Relevant code below (c# and ASP.NET core 2.1).

Requested permissions:

```
"User.Read Mail.ReadWrite"
```

Link to request authorisation:

```
$"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={appId}" +
   $"&response_type=code" +
   $"&redirect_uri={responseUrl}" +
   $"&response_mode=query" +
   $"&scope={permissions}" +
   $"&state={userManager.GetUserId(User)}";
```

Action to receive authorisation response:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("authentication/ms/receive-response/")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ReceiveAuthResponse(string code, string state)
{
    ApplicationUser applicationUser = await UserManager.GetApplicationUser(User);

    OfficeLinkConfiguration officeLinkConfiguration = new OfficeLinkConfiguration
    {
        ApplicationId = configuration.GetSection("OfficeLink").GetValue<string>("ApplicationId"),
        RequestedPermissions = configuration.GetSection("OfficeLink").GetValue<string>("RequestedPermissions"),
        RedirectUrl = configuration.GetSection("OfficeLink").GetValue<string>("ResponseUrl"),
        ClientSecret = configuration.GetSection("OfficeLink").GetValue<string>("Password"),
    };

    OfficeLinkProvider officeLinkProvider = new OfficeLinkProvider(officeLinkConfiguration, tokenStore);

    await officeLinkProvider.RequestAccessToken(applicationUser, code);

    return Redirect("/");
}
```

Request Access Token:

```
public async Task RequestAccessToken(ApplicationUser user, string authorisationCode)
{
    string tokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token";

    string postBody = $"client_id={Configuration.ApplicationId}" +
                      $"&scope={Configuration.RequestedPermissions}" +
                      $"&code={authorisationCode}" +
                      $"&redirect_uri={Configuration.RedirectUrl}" +
                      "&grant_type=authorization_code" +
                      $"&client_secret={Configuration.ClientSecret}";

    using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        string result = await webClient.UploadStringTaskAsync(tokenUrl, postBody);

        TokenResponse tokenResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResponse>(result);

        HandleAuthorisationResponse(user, tokenResponse);
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you written `"&grant_type=authorization_code"`  properly in the token request?

Comment: @RakihthaRR I think so, I copied it straight from the documentation. I've got the US spelling for authorization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by deleting the existing Application Password (secret) and creating a new one.